# Maintaining (version + redirect) in S3

Tags: deployment, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, version, browser-cache

So, far in our application, the `*.js` files were served directly from `apache`. For example, this was a script include in a jsp page : `/foo/v6565/my_script.js`. The `v6565` in the path is phony and an internal apache redirect, redirects `/foo/v6565/my_script.js` to `/foo/my_script.js`.

Whenever `my_script.js` is updated, `v<xxxx>` in the included jsp page (an internal tool does it based on the SVN revision of my_script) is updated - thus forcing the browser to fetch `my_script.js` again and not the cached version. I hope I am able to explain my current approach clearly.

[A different approach could have been to user /foo/my_script.js?v=5652. However, there was some caching issue (can't remember it) because of which the decision was taken to use /foo/v56564/ instead of adding version to the queryParam. I will dig into it, though]

Now, that we are moving all of our *.js files to an s3 bucket, I was wondering what would be a way of doing this?
The path from s3 bucket would look like : `mybucket.aws.com/js/my_script.js`. How to I insert the `version tag` + `redirection` for s3? Are there any other standard approaches used when resources are served from s3?

(I've read about page redirects on s3 resources but the redirects are to be written directly on the resources, which is not really applicable in my case)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think cache busting with `?v=<hash>` is pretty much standard now.

It has been [disadvised](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/), however that's a pretty old resource (though often cited) and I'm not sure if this is still true. Even your trusted [StackOverflow is using it with SHA1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112182/how-does-se-determine-the-css-and-js-version-parameter), so I guess it's good enough for everybody now.

Comment: Thank you for the SO pointer. This definitely adds a strong point for moving to ?v=<>